# F#: Substitute to .Replace("oldValue","newValue")

Tags: replace, f#, char, substitution

I'm playing around a little with **F#** syntax.

In Sweden we have a game called "Backslang" *(googletranslated from "Rövarspråk")*
The rules are quite simple. All words you say must be said in a specific way. While vocals are the same, each consonant must be pronounced with an "o" followed by the consonant again.

> I.e. **"L"** would be **"LOL"**, **"FRIDAY"** would be
>   **"FOFRORIDODAY"** and **"BALL"** would be **"BOBALOLLOL"**.

I wrote some code that looks really stupid but does its job.

```
let myWord (x:string) = 
    x.Replace("q","qoq").Replace("w","wow").Replace("r","ror").Replace("t","tot").Replace("p","pop").Replace("s","sos").Replace("d","dod").Replace("f","fof").Replace("g","gog").Replace("h","hoh").Replace("j","joj").Replace("k","kok").Replace("l","lol").Replace("z","zoz").Replace("x","xox").Replace("c","coc").Replace("v","vov").Replace("b","bob").Replace("n","non").Replace("m","mom").Replace("Q","QOQ").Replace("W","WOW").Replace("R","ROR").Replace("T","TOT").Replace("P","POP").Replace("S","SOS").Replace("D","DOD").Replace("F","FOF").Replace("G","GOG").Replace("H","HOH").Replace("J","JOJ").Replace("K","KOK").Replace("L","LOL").Replace("Z","ZOZ").Replace("X","XOX").Replace("C","COC").Replace("V","VOV").Replace("B","Bob").Replace("N","Non").Replace("M","Mom").ToLower()   

    myWord "ball"
```

> **F# Interactive:** val it : string = "bobalollol"

For the sake of readability, is there any way to give this code a better look?

I'm a newbie to F# and Functional Programming so any advices, protips and pointers are warmly welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.collect (string >> function
    | vowel when "aeiouyåäöAEIOUYÅÄÖ".Contains vowel -> vowel
    | consonant -> consonant + "o" + consonant )
```

[`String.collect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340454.aspx) applies a function to each char of a string.

Comment: If you combine this with FuleSnabel's `isVowel` function, it would be the best of both world's, IMO: `String.collect (function c when isVowel c -> string c | c -> sprintf "%co%c" c c)`

Comment: This solution is very neat! I like it a lot. Also fixed a small issue where the capital consonant would appear again as capital.

_**i.e.**_ 
 where **Ball** outputs **BoBalollol** now reads **Bobalollol.**


`| consonant -> consonant + "o" + consonant.ToLower())`

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps something like this:

```
let isVowel = function
  | 'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' | 'y' | 'å' | 'ä' | 'ö'
  | 'A' | 'E' | 'I' | 'O' | 'U' | 'Y' | 'Å' | 'Ä' | 'Ö' -> true
  | _ -> false

let lollify s =
  [| for c in s do if isVowel c then yield c else yield c; yield 'o';yield c |]
  |> System.String

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  printfn "%A" <| lollify "Ball"
  0
```

Note; this also has the benefit of not creating alot of temporary `string` objects.

Another option would be this:

```
let lollify s =
  s
  |> Seq.map (fun c -> if isVowel c then [|c|] else [|c;'o';c|])
  |> Seq.collect id
  |> Seq.toArray
  |> System.String
```

Comment: I find the second option more readable than the first, even if it's longer. +1

Comment: The implementation of `isVocal` demonstrates how F# enables one to write code that clearly and in a readable manner communicates what it does. Great layout of the code! I would call it `isVowel`, though ;)